# Definition of distribution, pseudofunction, and tempered distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

As a physicist, I do not know the difference

What is a pseudofunction? How is it different from a distribution? What is a tempered distribution?

If possible could you give examples and tell what the difference is?

Comment: umm why the downvote ? :(

Comment: "Pseudofunction" does not appear to be a standard technical term. What it means, if anything, will depend entirely on the context you find it in, and you should look to that context for a definition or explanation.

Comment: There's also the SHOUTING and the fact that the rest of your post is all lower case. $\hspace{1.51 in}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Henning, I have also never seen "pseudofunction" as a technical term. Check your source.

A *tempered* distribution is a continuous linear functional on the set of  [Schwarz functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) or "rapidly decreasing functions" in the same way as a regular distribution is a continuous linear functional on $C^\infty_c$, the set of smooth compactly supported functions.

Since there are more Schwarz functions than functions in $C^\infty_c$, the tempered distributions are a subset of the usual ones. The nice thing is about tempered distributions, $\mathcal S'$, is that the Fourier transform is a linear isomorphism $\mathcal S' \to \mathcal S'$, but in general you can't compute the Fourier transform of a usual distribution (at least the result won't be a distribution in general).

A typical example of a distribution that is not tempered is $f(x) = e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, (quite the opposite) but to the best of my knowledge....

A pseudofunction is a function derived as a remainder (or rump function), after performing an operation upon another function which originally may not be analytic or amenable to analysis. These pseudofunctions are also called **hypersingular functions** (used a lot, apparently, in the field of "fracture analysis"). In distribution theory they arise as a result of performing a Hadamard's "**finite part**" or **Cauchy "Principal Value"** operation on a non-analytic function. The remaining function is then analytic, and you can proceed further with analysis.

Specifically, Distributions, as you know, require an integral inner product between the given non-analytic function and a test function/bump function:

$\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Of course, every time you integrate, you must satisfy that the integral has meaning, ie. that it converges. In distribution theory, many times, the domain of integration is from 0 to $\infty$, within which, f(x) may also be unbounded somewhere.

The instances when the distribution integral may be divergent, are handled by pseudofunctions. (For finite parts, also denoted "Fp {G(x) }", Quite literally, you DISCARD the divergent terms that result when you substitute a Taylor series centered at the discontinuity (for eg. 0) for $\phi(t) = \phi(0) + t*\psi(t)$, in the above standard integral definition of a distribution, where $\psi(t)$ is a remainder term from the Taylor series expansion. The remaining rump of the distribution transform is a proper inner product and satisfies all the properties of a distribution: linearity, and continuity.

#### References

1. [Fracture Analysis (go to p.19).](http://books.google.com/books?id=LgWjAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA24&ots=oIr-Sr3zjx&dq=hadamard%20finite%20part%20motivation&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q=hadamard%20finite%20part%20motivation&f=false)
2. Zemanian's ["Distribution Theory Transform analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=loQUAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=zemanian&pg=PR9#v=onepage&q=zemanian&f=false)" (go to p. 15 and ch. 2 p. 57)